# Язык C, существуют ли соглашения использования const

Tags: c, const

Казалось бы, концепция **const** очень проста.

```
const int i = 1;// Запрещает изменять i.
```

Но...

Поработав с большим количеством библиотек, и написав определенное количество своих, я, как это обычно бывает, лишь запутался, осознавая, насколько все неоднозначно.

Когда и как использовать **const**? И стоит ли его использовать вообще? Учитывая, что изменение данных, которые являются **const**, - это неопределенное поведение.

Например, что мы можем сказать о следующей функции?:

```
void some_func(const void *const _value);
```

То, что функция использует *правила хорошего тона* и не изменяет ни аргумент-указатель, ни данные, адрес которых хранится в этом аргументе?

Или, может быть, данные, на которые указывает аргумент-указатель, обязательно должны быть неизменяемыми?

Вот еще пример:

```
extern const int i;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a = i;
    do_something();
    int b = i;

    if (a != b)
    {
       // Возможно.
       // i нельзя изменить на этой стороне.
       // Но, теоретически, на той стороне i может меняться.
    }
}
```

Я почитал обсуждение, в котором принимал участие *Линус Торвальдс*. Он достаточно подробно и детально описывает ряд проблем (жаль, что на английском), которые связаны с **const** квалификатором. Но я так и не понял, как эти проблемы решать.

Есть ли какие-то рецепты? Может быть, в вашей компании имеется удобное соглашение на использование **const**? Используете ли вы его вообще?

Comment: По-моему, тут никаких разночтений нет - функция никак не изменяет переданные ей данные, точка.

Comment: Сама функция не изменяет, верно (если не делать хаки). Но, возможно, данная функция передает аргумент-указатель куда-то дальше, а там уже неизвестно, что с ним будет происходит.

Comment: Конечно, в общем случае, если функция принимает указатель на неизменяемые данные, то все подфункции должны принимать этот же указатель в аналогичном виде, чтобы сохранять логическую непротиворечивость. Но, существует огромное количество ситуаций, когда мы вообще не можем сказать, что будет происходить с этой переменной. Это обратные вызовы, внешние библиотеки и прочее.

Comment: Гарантировать неизменяемость константных данных - ответственность функции (уж раз там написано `const`). Если эта функция передаёт входные данные куда-то ещё, где эти данные могут быть изменены, то функция должна сделать копию этих данных и передавать уже копию. Либо, функция не должна заявлять, что она не изменяет данные и убрать `const` из объявления.

Comment: Если сформулировать проблему проще, то аргумент типа const void *const может обозначать совершенно разные вещи: функция требует, чтобы аргумент был именно такого типа, либо же перед передачей в функцию аргумент конвертируется в заданный тип с целью предохранения его от изменений в функции до момента, когда аргумент будет передан куда-то дальше по вызовам.

Comment: Нельзя так делать. Функция либо гарантирует неизменность данных, либо нет. В этом суть контракта. И функция не требует, она гарантирует.

Comment: Хм, можно подробнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что значение `const` меняется в зависимости от контекста.

- При использовании как верхняя часть типа переменной или аргумента в определении функции

```cpp
// значение x не должно изменяется
int const x = ...;
void foo(int const x) { … }
// значение p_x не должно изменяться
// значение, на которое указывает p_x, может изменяться
int * const p_x = ...;
void foo(int * const p_x) { … }
```

- При использовании в перенаправленном типе переменной или аргумента в определении функции

```cpp
// значение p_x может изменяться
// значение, на которое указывает p_x, не должно изменяться через этот указатель
int const * p_x = ...;
void foo(int const * p_x) { … }
```

- При использовании как верхняя часть типа аргумента в объявлении функции вообще мало о чем говорит

```cpp
// может ли меняться x - неизвестно, в определении может быть void foo(int x) { ... }
void foo(int const x);
// может ли меняться p_x - неизвестно, в определении может быть void foo(int * p_x) { … }
// значение, на которое указывает p_x, может изменяться 
void foo(int * const p_x);
```

- При использовании в перенаправленном типе аргумента в объявлении функции

```cpp
// может ли меняться p_x - неизвестно, в определении может быть void foo(int const * const p_x) { … }
// значение, на которое указывает p_x, не должно изменяться через этот указатель
void foo(int const * p_x);
```

Еще стоит заметить, что сигнатура определения функции в общем случае может вообще не соответствовать объявлению - но это откровенный косяк. Также отсутствует семантика говорящая что "переменная, на которую указывает указатель, не может изменяться в принципе". Любой указатель на const что-то говорит только о том, что данные не должны меняться через этот конкретные указатель.

Comment: Если указатель указывает на константные данные const object *p, то это может значить как минимум две вещи. Таким способом могли обеспечить защиту изменяемого объекта от изменения в заданной локальной области, например, в теле функции. Либо же p указывает на объект, который в самом деле является константным. Тогда попытка изменить такой объект, например, через хак указателя, приведет к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: @Максим Нет, если указатель указывает на константные данные (const object *p), то это совершенно ничего не говорит о том, являются ли данные на самом деле неизменяемыми или все-таки могут изменяться. Любая попытка изменить данные на которые указывает такой указатель - откровенное простреливание собственной ноги. А хак с катом указателя допустим только если в последующем через полученный указатель на изменяемые данные никаких попыток изменения этих данных не будет Разработчик может отставить комментарий, что данные на самом деле неизменяемые, но делать такой вывод из наличия const будет ошибкой

Comment: @Максим Это ситуация не является допустимой, так как функция снимает const с данных с целью их дальнейшего изменения. То, что это изменение может произойти не в самой функции, а где-то дальше - уже не столь важно. Как я уже написал выше - хак с кастом указателя допустим только если в последующем через полученный указатель на изменяемые данные никаких попыток изменения этих данных не будет.

Comment: Кажется, я начинаю понимать. То есть, функция, которая принимает аргумент (const void *_p), просто гарантирует, что она не будет менять данные, на которые указывает _p? Но она не может знать, являются ли эти данные в самом деле константными или нет?

Comment: Но, если, допустим, функция вставки указателя на изменяемые данные в связный список принимает указатель на неизменяемые данные, а при добавлении данных осуществляет new_node->data = (void*)_data, это допустимо? Естественно, подразумевается, что в списке хранятся указатели на изменяемые данные.

Comment: @Максим Именно так. Кстати вроде была инициатива введения обозначения как раз для неизменяемых данных (`immutable` кажется), которое могло бы использоваться в такой ситуации (и позволить компилятору делать дополнительные оптимизации на основе знания, что данные никогда не могут измениться).

Comment: Нет, это будет совершенно недопустимо. Если в списке хранятся указатели на изменяемые данные, то `(void*)_data` в функции, принимающей указатель на неизменяемые данные будет снимать const c целью дальнейшего изменения данных. То, что это изменение может произойти не в самой функции, а где-то дальше - уже не столь важно. Как я уже написал выше - хак с кастом указателя допустим только если в последующем через полученный указатель на изменяемые данные никаких попыток изменения этих данных не будет. (Кажется я уже начинаю повторяться).

Comment: Короче говоря, функция для добавления данных в список с изменяемыми данными должна принимать строго указатели на изменяемые данные.

Comment: Так сама функция не изменяет данные. Она просто конструирует новый узел, вставляет его в список и связывает созданный узел с данными, указатель на которые был передан в функцию вставки. Затем функция завершается. Сама же функция не меняет данных, хотя данные могут быть изменены через связный список, в который были помещены. Вот в чем неоднозначность.

Comment: Можно провести аналогию с **memcpy(void*, const void *, size_t)**. Функция говорит, что данные, на которые указывает второй аргумент-указатель, не будут меняться в функции, но это не значит, что эти данные не могут быть изменены вне функции **memcpy()**. Так же данные не обязаны быть константными.